# Is it possible to stop/interrupt calls to File.Exists()

Tags: c#

In the following code I have a class that searches for a file by checking if the file exists in three folder levels, everything is working great, the search is really fast. The only issue I have with this code is that if a user types some file name and hits search to call the `recursiveRealTimeSearch()` method but immediately after she/he realizes that she/he entered the wrong file name and then she/he types a new name, the previous search never stops. What I would like to be able to do is stop previous searches every time the `recursiveRealTimeSearch()` method is called, is that possible.

How can I stop previous searches every time `recursiveRealTimeSearch()` method is called?

#### Main Search Class

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows;

    namespace MyApp.Model
    {
        public class SearchEngine
        {
            string _fileName;
            string _fileExtension;
            string _url;

            public SearchEngine(string fileName, string fileExtension, string url)
            {
                _fileName = fileName;
                _fileExtension = fileExtension;
                _url = url;
            }

            public string recursiveRealTimeSearch()
            {
                // Perform search only if user has access to the specified URLs, otherwise do nothing.
                if (Directory.Exists(_url))
                {
                    /// FIRST LEVEL CHECK
                    var pathFirstLevelSearch = System.IO.Path.Combine(_url, _fileName + _fileExtension);
                    if (File.Exists(pathFirstLevelSearch))
                    {
                        var path = pathFirstLevelSearch;
                        return path;
                    }

                    /// SECOND LEVEL CHECK
                    string[] secondLevelDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(_url);
                    foreach (var dir in secondLevelDirectories)
                    {
                        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, _fileName + _fileExtension);
                        if (File.Exists(path))
                        {
                            return path;
                        }
                        /// THIRD LEVEL CHECK
                        var thirdLevelDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(dir);
                        foreach (var dir2 in thirdLevelDirectories)
                        {
                            path = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir2, _fileName + _fileExtension);
                            if (File.Exists(path))
                            {
                                return path;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
    }
```

#### Class Model

```
    public class SearchEngineModel{
            public void search(){
                SearchEngine findPdf = new SearchEngine("FileName", ".PDF", pdfDirectory);
                fileURLPdf = findPdf.recursiveRealTimeSearch();
            }

            private void openPdfFile_Click()
            {          
                if (fileURLPdf != null) {
                    openFile(fileURLPdf);
                }
                else {
                    MessageBox.Show("File was not found!", "File Not Found", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                }
            }

            private void openFile(string path)
            {
                if (path != null) {

                    bool fileExists = File.Exists(path);
                    if (fileExists) {
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
                    }
                    else {
                        MessageBox.Show("The file not found!", "File Not Found", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: I suggest adding a [CanellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken) parameter to the method and in the loops call ThowIfCancellationRequested() on each iteration

Comment: Hmm, I'll take a look at the CancellationToken to see how it can be used. Thanks

Comment: @KlausGütter - I'm a little lost here, I added the token parameter to `public string recursiveRealTimeSearch(CancellationToken token)`  and added a `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` inside each of the `foreach` statements but I'm not sure how to cancel the request from when the `recursiveRealTimeSearch()` method is called.  Can someone please elaborate a little more on this?

Comment: Create a CancellationTokenSource somewhere up and call its Cancel method when you want to abort the search.

Comment: I added a `Stop Search` button to stop the search by calling the cancel method `tokenSource.Cancel();` but after the cancel method is called I can no longer make another search. Do I need to resume the tokenSource? If yes, how can it be resumed, I don't see a cancel or resume method. Again the search works as normal until I call the cancel method, after that the search stops working.

Comment: Create a new one each time you start a search.

Comment: @KlausGütter - By creating a new token at the beginning of the search the cancel never happens. BTW here is how I'm creating the tokens.  First I declared them as follow `CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new` `CancellationTokenSource();  CancellationToken token;` then in the constructor `token = tokenSource.Token;` then in the Stop Search button `tokenSource.Cancel();` then in the search method `CancellationToken token;` I hope it makes sense.

Comment: I meant: create a new `CancellationTokenSource` each time (and of course: use the Token of the freshly created CancellationTokenSource in the method).

Comment: I got it working. Thanks a lot for your help.  Please considere posting an answer so I can mark it as the right answer since you basically answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I was able to accomplish what I needed by using `CanellationToken` as suggested by `@Klaus Gütter`. In the following code a search can be cancelled by calling the `cancelSearch()` method.

```
using System.Threading;

public class SearchEngineModel{
        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;
        CancellationToken token;

        public void search(){
            // create a new CancellationTokenSource on every search
            tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            token = tokenSource.Token;

            SearchEngine findPdf = new SearchEngine("FileName", ".PDF", pdfDirectory);
            fileURLPdf = findRPdf.recursiveRealTimeSearch(token);
        }

        private void openPdfFile_Click()
        {          
            if (fileURLPdf != null) {
                openFile(fileURLPdf);
            }
            else {
                MessageBox.Show("File was not found!", "File Not Found", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            }
        }

        private void openFile(string path)
        {
            if (path != null) {

                bool fileExists = File.Exists(path);
                if (fileExists) {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
                }
                else {
                    MessageBox.Show("The file not found!", "File Not Found", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                }
            }
        }

    // new method to be able to cancel the search with a button click.
    private void cancelSearch()
    {
        tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        token = tokenSource.Token;
        tokenSource.Cancel();
    }
}


namespace MyApp.Model
{
    public class SearchEngine
    {
        string _fileName;
        string _fileExtension;
        string _url;

        public SearchEngine(string fileName, string fileExtension, string url)
        {
            _fileName = fileName;
            _fileExtension = fileExtension;
            _url = url;
        }

        public string recursiveRealTimeSearch(CancellationToken token)
        {
            // Perform search only if user has access to the specified URLs, otherwise do nothing.
            if (Directory.Exists(_url))
            {
                /// FIRST LEVEL CHECK
                var pathFirstLevelSearch = System.IO.Path.Combine(_url, _fileName + _fileExtension);
                if (File.Exists(pathFirstLevelSearch))
                {
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();// cancel if needed
                    var path = pathFirstLevelSearch;
                    return path;
                }

                /// SECOND LEVEL CHECK
                string[] secondLevelDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(_url);
                foreach (var dir in secondLevelDirectories)
                {
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();// cancel if needed
                    string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, _fileName + _fileExtension);
                    if (File.Exists(path))
                    {
                        return path;
                    }
                    /// THIRD LEVEL CHECK
                    var thirdLevelDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(dir);
                    foreach (var dir2 in thirdLevelDirectories)
                    {
                        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();// cancel if needed
                        path = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir2, _fileName + _fileExtension);
                        if (File.Exists(path))
                        {
                            return path;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
}
```

Comment: Why do you create a new `CancellationTokenSource` in `cancelSearch`? This is unnneccessary. Just do a `tokenSource?.Cancel();`

Comment: Ahh, the search worked better after removing it from the `cancelSearch` method.  Before removing it, the search wasn't stopping if one of the searches has already started, it was only stopping the other searches below but now it seems to be stopping all searches immediately, even if it has been started. Thanks a lot for pointing that out.

Comment: There are some other mistakes in this version.  Rather critically, `findPdf.recursiveRealTimeSearch()` fails to pass the argument.

Comment: Shoot. I actually have it in my real project, I just missed it when I posted it here.  FIXED: Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: This is great-- it is [encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20more%20than,own%20question%20at%20any%20time.) to answer your own question. Just don't forget to mark it as the answer!